# Enhance Google search by incorporating Stack Overflow

Tags: script, search

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

This is a userscript for browsers (Chrome/Firefox) which can give you an overview of your programming-related search. The detailed functions are listed below:

- Spot the programming term in your Google search input;
- Return the tag wiki to that term and a link to our website for more details;
- A knowledge graph of the input term so that you can have an overview of it and even refine your search. Maybe some surprise to you!

All data comes from Stack Overflow (before March 8th, 2015) and we hope it can help you carry out efficient search.

### Update

**Version 0.1**

- Reduce the node number in the graph for clearer view;
- Right click the node to see the basic intro of the node;
- Fix the bug of the conflict between the plugin and Google Box in Firefox.

### Install

- Install Tampermonkey for Firefox or Greasemonkey for Chrome;
- Go to our [github](https://github.com/ccywch/knowledgeGraph_plugin) (https://github.com/ccywch/knowledgeGraph_plugin) to download the user script and paste the code into Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey;
- You are welcome to improve the code and enjoy it!

### Contact

For any questions, bugs, suggestions, please leave a comment or answer under this post or contact me in my email chen0966@e.ntu.edu.sg.